# Setting this filter gives 'Syntax error in query expression'

Tags: vba, ms-access

This code in a button OnClick event

```
  With frm
     .Filter = strWhere  ' Error here
     .FilterOn = True
     .OrderBy = strOrderBy
     .OrderByOn = True
  End With
```

where strWhere is

```
 "([Orders].[ID] in (SELECT [Job Orders].OrderFID     
  FROM [Job Orders]     
  WHERE (([Job Orders].BillJobFID)=1324)));"
```

gives 'Syntax error in query expression', but if I take the same where clause and create a select statement, it works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE    
([Orders].[ID] in (SELECT [Job Orders].OrderFID    
FROM [Job Orders]     
WHERE (([Job Orders].BillJobFID)=1324)));"
```

I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I posted was because I was at a dead end about how to debug this.
Turns out that my problem was that I was comparing apples and oranges.

It works when I add the filter to "Select * from Orders".
But that isn't what the form does.

Once I added the filter to the **query used as the recordset** on the form, the problem immediately became apparent.

Answer (score 2):

The Filter property does not take a complete SQL statement so the semi-colon is not called for and that is cause of error. Would be same case for WHERE ARGUMENT of OpenForm and OpenReport methods.

Also, can simplify:

`"ID IN (SELECT OrderFID FROM [Job Orders] WHERE BillJobFID=1324)"`

Comment: "the semi-colon is not called for"  That's what I thought too. But I got the same error with and without, and the old version that worked had it, so I left it in, in case I was missing something.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I tested with and without semi-colon and this answer is result of that. Error with, works without.

Comment: Good point on the simplification.  Yeah, I don't know. Now that I have the query fixed, it works fine with or without. Doesn't seem like it should. But now that I have it fixed, I can take it out without worrying about what the old version did.